# Appending Text from an HTML Form to an Existing Text File

Tags: javascript, html, activex

Background: I am trying to create a bookmarks page that will exist on a file server. I want to have a text file (containing my list of bookmarks) located in the same folder as the HTML file, but I also want users to be able to add bookmarks to that text file using an HTML form.

I am trying to append the text from the HTML form to the end of an existing text file in the same folder as my HTML file. The following code I have almost works, but it's creating a new file on my desktop instead of editing the existing file. Any ideas how I can fix this?

```
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script> 
            function Write(link, title) 
            {
                var fso, f, r;
                var ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2;
                fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
                f = fso.OpenTextFile("links.txt", ForWriting, true);
                f.Write(link + title);
                f.Close();
            }
        </script>
    </head>
```

```
        <form onSubmit="Write(this['link'].value, this['title'].value)">
            <input type="text" name="link" id="link" value="Link" size="20">
            <input type="text" name="title" id="title" value="Title" size="20">

            <input type="submit" value="Add Bookmark">
        </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code doesn't create a new file, unless the file doesn't exist. When you pass `2` as the second parameter to `OpenTextFile` method, the file is opened for writing, i.e. `Write` will replace all the text in the file with new content.

To fix this, you've to pass `8` as the second parameter to `OpenTextFile`, that makes `Write` to append the new content at the end of the file.